# How to overlay view over navigation controller bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uinavigationcontroller

I've sorta got a little problem. I'm trying to add a popoverview to my app but part of the popoverview get's hidden by my navigation controller bar. How can I make my popoverview overlay over top of the navcontrollerbar? Here's an image of the problem: http://img593.imageshack.us/img593/4056/viewn.jpg

Here's my code I'm working with:

```
- (IBAction)onButtonClick:(UIButton *)button {

if (self.popoverController) {
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    self.popoverController = nil;
    [button setTitle:@"Show Popover" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else {
    UIViewController *contentViewController = [[WEPopoverContentViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    self.popoverController = [[[WEPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentViewController] autorelease];
    [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame 
                                            inView:self.view 
                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown
                                          animated:YES];
    [contentViewController release];
    [button setTitle:@"Hide Popover" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
}
```

Is there anyway to make this popover above the navigation controller bar?

Hopefully someone knows how to fix this problem, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could this be related to the inView parameter to `WEPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:`? Instead of presenting it in `self.view` could you present further up in the view hierarchy (like in `self.view.window`)?

Comment: OMG!!! I tried that but I didn't specially try self.view.window. I tried self.window and super.view and etc. Thanks so much. It works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

ohh..I got it..I changed line in function

```
- (void)presentPopoverFromRect:(CGRect)rect 
                    inView:(UIView *)theView 
  permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections 
                  animated:(BOOL)animated {
```

in WEPopOverController 
from `[keyView addSubview:backgroundView];`
to `[theView addSubview:backgroundView];`